# How to ignore tests by category (trait) name in NCrunch

Tags: xunit, ncrunch

I'm using xUnit + NCrunch. I've got some tests marked as integrational:

```
[Trait("Category", "Integration")]
```

How do I skip those tests in NCrunch? The tests *are not* in the separate assembly so I cannot ignore the entire assembly completely.